# scala - how to substitute env value for another variable using regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a variable aa which is having reference to an environment variable.
And I need to substitute the value using regex

```
Name = TEMP
Value = C:\Users\asus101\AppData\Local\Temp
aa: String = "${TEMP}_Report"
```

Expected output:

```
p2:  C:\Users\asus101\AppData\Local\Temp_Report
```

The code that I tried

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

   val aa = "${TEMP}\\Report"
    for ((name,value) <- System.getenv() ) {
       val p1 = """\${XX}""".replace("XX",name).r
      val p2 = p1.replaceAllIn(aa,value)
      if(name=="TEMP") {
        println("Name = " + name)
        println("Value = " + value)
        println("p2 = " + p2 )
      }
```

I'm getting the error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
\${USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE}
 ^
```

what is wrong with the regex

Comment: @jwvh.. sorry if it is confusing.. using ````aa.replace("${"+ name +"}",value )```` I'm able to resolve.. but how do i solve it with regex?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell, but I think this gets at what you're after.

```
import scala.util.Properties._

val pttrn = raw".*(\$$\{\s*(\w+)\s*\})".r
val strA = "${ME}:my ${HOME} is Gnome and my ${BROWSER} is     fine."

val strB =
  strA.split("(?<=})").map {
    case s @ pttrn(a,b) => envOrNone(b).fold(s)(s.replace(a,_))
    case s => s
  }.mkString
//strB: String = ${ME}:my /home/jwvh is Gnome and my firefox is     fine.
```

There is no `$ME` in my environment, so no substitution there, but the `$HOME` and `$BROWSER` values are pulled out and substituted.